Increase error counter in CircuitBreaker later from values in the body of the response
We have a set of connectors with external providers using REST APIs. We use HttpClient and Polly to make resilient queries to the endpoints.
One of the providers is actually an intermediary between several other providers and has this special behaviour: when the upstream provider is receiving too many requests, our intermediary connector returns a HTTP 200 status. However, in the body of the response, we can analyze the contents and determine that the upstream provider is returning a 429 Too Many Requests status code.
We use a Circuit Breaker policy to query, we receive a 200 but we don't know it's actually a 429 until we process the message. The project is a big aggregator and this parsing can happen quite far away from the call.
Is there a way we can modify the Circuit Breaker error counters so that it changes its status based on the contents of the response body? We would need to be able to change this from a different location in code, not from the Http call itself but afterwards.
I've read about this policies registry, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case.
Thanks in advance.

Can you please share with us which Polly version are you targeting? Some of your links are pointing to the V7 API while others to the V8.

We are using v7, but we are open to upgrade if it's necessary,

I've left a post with V7 in the focus. Do you want to me to extend that with V8?

We're using v7 currently, so your answer is suited for our scenario. If somebody wants explanation for v8, (s)he can request it.

In this post I assumed that you are using the V7 API.
What to decorate?
Circuit breaker and every other policies are generic enough to be used against any domain. In other words, you don't have to tie the Circuit Breaker to the direct HTTP calls. So, you can decorate that method which has already partially/entirely processed the response body.
If you need to decorate directly the HttpClient then it is also feasible to parse the response body and act accordingly. Here you can find a couple of different options how to do this.
When to break?
In case of V7 the standard Circuit Breaker is counting the consecutive errors. That means the successive error count exceeds the predefined threshold then the circuit breaks.
If you want you can also manually control when should it open or close. This can be done via the Isolate and Reset calls. Please bear in mind in this case there is no automatic state transition. You have to explicitly call the Reset to transition back from Isolated to Closed.
